# Datatables and createdRow callback hot to add data attribute to rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vL3yw0z2/17/

This work fine:

```
$(row).addClass("classtest"+id);
```

But this not:

```
$(row).data("rowid", id);
```

I can't find the problem.

Comment: "I can't find the problem" - what behavior are you expecting and  what are you getting?

Comment: i'd like to add, for each row created, a "data-rowid" attribute. Btw i've solved with: $(row).attr("data-rowid", id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you believe `data()` sets `data-xxx` attributes. It does not. jQuerys `data` feature is just a convenient way to

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

To set a HTML5 `data-xxx` attribute use `attr` :

```
$(row).attr("data-rowid", id);
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/vL3yw0z2/18/**